# Database schema vs database structure

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

What is the difference between database schema and database structure?
I am learning dbms and these two words are confusing for me. Dint find much information anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Database schema and database structure can be used interchangeably, more or less. Most software developers will understand them to mean the same thing.

Schema in particular is used in two different ways:

- A schema is like a folder that contains tables. You use statements like `CREATE SCHEMA <schemaname>`, `DROP SCHEMA <schemaname>`, `USE <schemaname>`. In MySQL, `SCHEMA` and `DATABASE` are synonyms in most contexts.
- A schema is sometimes used to refer to the full definition of all objects in your project, including the schema, tables, indexes, procedures, functions, etc.